# How to reload current page in previous page after location.back (not SPA)

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout, router

Cannot call a function in previous page's lifecycle which the page being killed.

I try to reload `page A` after `page B` being killed:

```
    // in Page B
    function backAndReload() {
        history.back()
        location.reload()
    }
```

The `page A` not being reloaded, because after `history.back()` the `page B` was killed and the code `location.reload()` will never be executed.

So I set a timeout:

```
    // in Page B
    function backAndReload() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            location.reload()
        }, 1000)
        history.back()
    }
```

But it didn't work as well.

So how to perform a task in a being killed page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this in case of a non-SPA page, because when the page being killed the *js* thread will be terminated as well, so all the unfinished task will be cleared as well.